# What are the other ways to get from Ibiza (Spain) to Barcelona except the airplane?

Tags: transportation, spain, barcelona

I'm going to visit Ibiza (spain) in October and my return flight is from Barcelona. I'm wondering is there cheaper way to get to Barcelona than on the airplane?

Answer (score 5):

You can look at [Direct Ferries](http://www.directferries.com/?_ga=1.109874316.826136231.1472486022) to book your travel to Ibiza by sea.  And if there is a Ferry you can probably rent a private boat too but you'll have to look for it.

Comment: Here is a direct link to the relevant page on Direct Ferries: http://www.directferries.com/barcelona_ibiza_ferry.htm